# Dynamic Order App

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible, without using opportunities, to directly add products (custom object) to order (another custom object)? How?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the rules in your organization? You do not need to use opportunities if you don't want to.

Comment: Okay, one more question, is it possible to get the total of all the selected products and declare that as the order grand total amount without having to use order line item (assume this is also a custom object) as another object?

Comment: @lol A database requires a many-to-many relationship to associate an arbitrary number of records (e.g. Orders) to another arbitrary number of records (e.g. Products). I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but you do need a "line item" type object to do what you're trying to do properly. At that point, you can just use roll-up summary fields.

Comment: @sfdcfox you've been a great help also, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol -- I'm surmising that you want to mimic the functionality of the products selection "wizard" used by SFDC OOB for Opportunities, Quotes, etc. but instead applied to your custom object.

Would it be so simple.

The OOB product selection wizard constructs a line item object that has a currency, a lookup to a pricebookEntry (which in turn is a junction to Pricebook2 and Product2), a quantity, price, and description.

You would need to replicate this functionality (including setting the pricebook, a search filter, checkbox record selection, and then dialogs to set quantity/price/description).  Such replication would require Visualforce

Comment: So...seems like creating a certain line item object is a must have approach. Any way, I've finally gotten the idea. Thank you.